# Is there a reward for collecting all lore tomes from a series?

Tags: diablo-iii

During my hack-and-slash sessions, I encountered some lore tomes that seem to be a part of a larger set. I have encountered three sets so far, Lian's, Deckard Cain's and Lachnadan's. Is there some sort of reward for "collecting them all"? I assume there would be some achievement and maybe banner widgets, but maybe there's something more to that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no real reward such as a useful item. However, you do get various achievements and some XP for each book.

The meta achievement is [*Grand Lorekeeper of Sanctuary*](http://d3db.com/achievement/i/grand-lorekeeper-of-sanctuary)

Here is the full list of "read lore" achievements:

- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/historian-of-the-high-heavens
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/historian-of-arreat
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/historian-of-caldeum
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/historian-of-tristram
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/archival-studies
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/espionage
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/eavesdropper
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/taking-notes
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/know-it-all
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/primary-sources
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/judge-of-character
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/a-quick-study
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/beastmaster-of-the-high-heavens
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/beastmaster-of-arreat
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/beastmaster-of-caldeum
- http://d3db.com/achievement/i/beastmaster-of-tristram

Comment: and xp for each lore book!